# Pass through Query Fails with Stored Procedure using Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, dsn

I've created a stored procedure in SQL Server that in turn is using a linked server to query two databases. The results are returned as expected in Query Analyzer, but when I try running the same stored procedure using a pass-through query in Access I get an authentication error.

Access has no problem quering either database when I use the passthrough and either DSN, it's only when I try to execute the stored procedure.

It almost seems like the DSN connection can't pass on the credentials to the linked server via the current DSN server.

The user is a member of domain admins, has full rights to both sql servers and I'm using Integrated Security on both DSNs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic double hop issue. The article [Configuring Linked Servers for Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580.aspx) discusses how to work around this. But you'll note that one of the first requirements listed is:

- The user Active Directory property, **Account is sensitive and cannot be delegated,** must not be selected.

which is almost certainly selected for the domain admin account (or at least, it should be in a well run domain)